# fopen in html5 doesn't display anything

Tags: php, windows, html, netbeans, fopen

I need to display a `.txt` file in read and write, but the file didn't appeared in my div `#div11`

```
<div id="div11">
<?php
$fichier = fopen("txt/texte.txt", "r+");
fclose($fichier);
?>
</div>
```

I've made a test before to know if `$fichier` was equal to NULL but it's not the case.

I've looked "Developer tools" of chrome too, and there's nothing between the marks of my div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just opening a file handle an close it afterwards, you don't output or even access the content of the file. If you just want to output the file contents, use something different, e.g. `readfile('/path/to/File')` or `echo file_get_contents('/path/to/File');`.

If you still want to use fopen, take a look at the `fgets()` function in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

Comment: and what should i do if i want to modify the txt file and save with new data ?

Comment: Then `fopen()` is the right way, for writing have a look at the `fwrite()` function at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php);

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're just opening the file, you're not displaying its content.

To display the file content, you can do this :

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("txt/texte.txt");
?>
```